What is the criss-cross C-N bond in furazolidone?
What is the cross C-N bond in the structure of furazolidone?  I have never seen this notation before and couldn't find anything on it.


It means it is a double bond without specifying whether it is E or Z

Depending on the sketcher you use (e.g., ChemDraw, ChemDoodle, Biovia Draw; the sketchers in databases of for instance Reaxys, or PubChem) this particular double bond is called ambiguous (double) bond to refer to/to search both (E), and (Z) isomer.

It means it is a double bond without specifying whether it is E or Z
From Wikipedia

A crossed double-bond has been used sometimes; it is no longer considered an acceptable style for general use but may still be required by computer software.


For answer you need to add some more, source in particular.

@Mithoron The 2008 compilation by Brecher in Pure Appl. Chem. doesn't include it, though one by 2006 apparently did. Would a public link to (an elder version's manual) of ChemDoodle suffice? Or a classification "colloquial" / "informal" as it (perhaps) is not backed by IUPAC?

@Waylander Though I see crossed double bonds more frequently than ones either (E), or (Z) and then with a wavy bond to indicate the ambiguous / non-assigned character, maybe -- backed by Wikipedia -- one can hint to this alternative form of writing.
